# The main ingredient is blueberries or the main ingredient is blueberry?

Tags: grammatical-number, be, uncountable-nouns, predicative-complements

Which sentence is grammatically accurate or they both acceptable? "The main ingredient is blueberries" sounds better to me. "The main ingredient" is indicative of one type of ingredient, so does that mean that it doesn't matter if "blueberry" is in plural or singular form?

Comment: As has been discussed here before, subject-verb agreement (and this may be notional, as in 'Fish and chips was on the menu') is governed by grammatical rules, not verb-object or verb-complement. So, the choice between 'blueberry' and 'blueberries' is governed by other factors. While non-count variants are available hereabouts ('The main ingredient is apple / chicken'), with smaller, etically countable entities (apple will probably be mashed), the count usage is preferred.

Comment: If it was an extremely small pie or tart, it might have only one blueberry in it, and it was the main ingredient. In this case, *the main ingredient is a blueberry* is not only correct grammatically, but accurate. If it has more than one blueberry, I would avoid the potential problem by saying *blueberries constitute the main ingredient* (and here you cannot say *blueberry constitutes the main ingredient*).

Answer (score 3):

A [blueberry pie](http://www.bettycrocker.com/recipes/classic-blueberry-pie/78e913d6-7e53-4ee3-bec5-ca38083b70b0) has **blueberries** as one of its main ingredients.
Likewise, a *strawberry cheesecake* needs more than one strawberry.

I would opt for the plural version when listing any berry fruits as ingredients.

> The main ingredient **is blueberries**.

However, if the recipe requires that the berries be desiccated, or crushed so their juices are extracted then the OP *can* use the singular noun form

> 1. Blueberry **Vodka** (gorzałka) - the Vodka’s main ingredient **is blueberry** (Vaccinium myrtillus), a dark blue fruit growing in local forests.
> 2. The invention discloses a blueberry **tablet** and a preparation method thereof. The main compositions of the blueberry tablet **are blueberry powder**, carrot powder, medlar powder and chrysanthemum powder...
> 3. Blueberry **pie**: A fruit pie (or tart) in which the principal filling ingredient **is blueberries**. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_pies,_tarts_and_flans))

Comment: Please look at link, the word *blueberries* is used in the recipe.

Comment: Surely that vodka's *main* ingredient is water.

Comment: @RegDwigнt take that up with the author, I thought exactly the same myself. Let's say that after water, blueberries is the vodka's main ingredient.

Answer (score 0):

The heart of the question is whether you use *ingredient* to refer to type or substance.

> **Ingredient** *noun*
>   Any of the foods or substances that are combined to make a particular dish
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ingredient)

Recipes often list ingredients with their quantity:

> Ingredients ...
>   6 sweet potatoes ...
>   [- jamieoliver](http://www.jamieoliver.com/recipes/vegetables-recipes/sweet-potato-with-marshmallow/#2eAZQLT5bWGCsU5u.97)

So if you follow the way *recipes* use the word *ingredient*, you might say

> The main ingredient is blueberries.

On the other hand, consider one recipe consisting of 2 eggs, some oil and some salt, and another that is identical except that it calls for 4 eggs. One would normally say that the second recipe has the *same* ingredients, but calls for more of *one* of the ingredients. Here's an example along these lines:

> How to Make 2 Different Recipes With the Same 5 Produce Ingredients
>   ... Three Egg Omelet ... three eggs
>   ... Rotini Bake ... 1 egg
>   [- spoonuniversity](http://spoonuniversity.com/lifestyle/how-to-make-2-different-recipes-with-the-same-5-produce-ingredients/)

Here, *ingredient* refers to the type of food, not its quantity. If you use the term in this sense, it should be singular:

> The main ingredient is blueberry.

My view is that the *singular* version is more formally correct. However, both of your alternatives communicate the idea effectively, and you would choose one or the other depending on whether you want to describe the *type* (blueberry) or the *substance* (blueberries) of the main ingredient.